# Failing to use LazyCache with Suave's WebPart

Tags: caching, f#, suave

I'm trying to use LazyCache (https://github.com/alastairtree/LazyCache) to cache some API requests.

The code goes as this:

```
let private cache = CachingService()
let doAPIStuff some parameters : WebPart = ...

let result = cache.GetOrAdd(hashedRequest, (fun _ -> doAPIStuff))
```

but I get this compile error:

```
  WebAPI.fs(59, 17): [FS0041] No overloads match for method 'GetOrAdd'.
Known types of arguments: string * ('a -> WebPart)
Available overloads:
 - (extension) IAppCache.GetOrAdd<'T>(key: string, addItemFactory: Func<'T>) : 'T // Argument 'addItemFactory' doesn't match
 - CachingService.GetOrAdd<'T>(key: string, addItemFactory: Func<Extensions.Caching.Memory.ICacheEntry,'T>) : 'T // Argument 'addItemFactory' doesn't match
```

These are the types available:

[image]

so I can do:

```
let doAPIStuff some parameters : Object = ...
```

and box my WebPart and it works fine. I understand that WebPart is a function (thanks for Fyodor in another question), but I don't understand why the function itself can't be in the cache as an object.

Comment: dont do `func _ -> doAPIStuff` (this can be `() -> ..` or `whatever -> ...`) - use `fun () -> doAPIStuff` - this should be able to be implicitly cast to `Func<'T>` - if not add `Func<'T> (fun () -> ..)`

Comment: PS: the way you defined it there it'll be probably rather pointless to cache the function-object - you'll do the complete computation once you apply it to the `some parameters` later (did you forget to provide the parametrs in `fun () -> doAPIStuff my parameters`?)

Comment: @Carsten, yes I guess I messed up my pseudo code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to explicitly create `Func` delegate in this case, otherwise F# compiler cannot distinguish between the two overloads.

The type of the second argument (in the basic case) is `Func<'T>` i.e. a function taking `unit` and returning the value to be cached. This also means that, inside this function, you should call `doAPIStuff` with the parameters as arguments.

Assuming this is in some `actualRequest` handler that takes `some`, `parameters`, the following should work:

```
let cache = CachingService()

let doAPIStuff some parameters : WebPart = 
  failwith "!"

let actualRequest some parameters = 
  let hashedRequest = some + parameters
  let result = 
    cache.GetOrAdd(hashedRequest, 
      Func<_>(fun () -> doAPIStuff some parameters))
  result
```

Comment: ok, I get it now; I didn't think that Func had to be explicit and that the compiler couldn't do the match, so I assumed the error was somewhere else. Thanks!